# How to use AutoPostback?

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework, webforms

For example:

```
Region: <asp:ListBox ID="RegionListBox2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="RegionName" DataValueField="RegionName"></asp:ListBox>

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

        Munipacility: <asp:DropDownList ID="MunipacilityDropDown" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Now 1 region contains many municipalities. When i click region in the listbox i want the municipalities from that region to show on the dropdownlist. For example when i click the button it works just perfectly it shows the municipalities, but i want for it to work somehow with postback so when i click it automatically will show them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.autopostback?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_UI_WebControls_ListControl_AutoPostBack) you just need to set ‘AutoPostback‘ to True.

Comment: Thank you bro, thats exactly what i wanted. I remembered from university i learned something with a function we somehow made things work with !isPostback or something like this but i didnt know exactly about this one. Thank you.